# Compress an alphanumeric string

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

Is there way to compress an alphanumeric string with length = 128 * 2 + 1 to shortest unique representation?

Comment: Strictly speaking no there isn't, because Kolmogorov complexity is not a computable function. But it really depends what you mean by "shortest representation". For example, Huffman coding is optimal subject to certain constraints.

Answer (score 7):

Of course, but the compression will depend on the available entropy in the string, as always.

I would look into [Huffman coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding), as a starting point. It's fairly easy to implement, and if you control both ends of the compress/decompress chain, you might get away with a well-chosen hard-coded coding, which saves even more space.

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering if you are only concerned about "shortest unique representation" and you *no longer need to get the original string back*, you can always apply and compute a hash.

It could be any of the SHA's or MD5 or some other one. It is generally guaranteed to be unique  but is one way and you cannot get the original data back.

That is how passwords are stored and verified all over the internet.

Comment: It is not guaranteed to be unique; it is just statistically unlikely that there is a duplicate.

Comment: That likelihood is good enough to have relied upon hashes as one way function. That is why they are so frequently used. You are sounding like "hashes are not unique so they shouldn't be used". Respectfully, i am amazed that some one down voted saying that about hashes. Perhaps the entire internet should consider your opinion and stop using hashes because they are not guaranteed. If it ought to be good for the extensive use it is actually in, it should be fine in the above scenario as long as original data is not needed.

Comment: Even programming languages use object hash to compare if they are the same. Perhaps they should listen to you too @Nevin. I seriously think you don't know what you are talking about. Read about properties of hashes in general and their usage. You are right about no guarantees i.e. it is not proven, but it is certainly relied upon for uniqueness. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function

Comment: Why the downvote? This is an excellent point. The chances of a successful birthday attack on such a small string are minimal - probably nigh on impossible.